# In the event of a space ship crash landing, where is the ship most likely to crash land?

Tags: planets, spaceships

[image: World Map]

This isn't a perfect map, and it's not a perfect model considering it is a 2D surface and my question relies on a 3D scenario, however it offers a general idea for what I want. In the bottom left hand side of the image, there is an area called "Pike's Point". My question is, how logical is it for a space ship to crash land there, and is there a higher likelihood for it to crash land somewhere else? If this map is part of a larger map, and there is more ocean surrounding the area that is depicted here, does that change the outcome of where it may land?

Comment: The answer to this relies on a lot of additional information. Was the ship in orbit? What kind of orbit? If not, where was the ship coming from?

Comment: Unfortunately, this is so incredibly opinion-based that it's likely to get a number of close votes as currently formatted. You might try posting this in the sandbox to get some help on how to ask in manner which gets you what you're looking for without being so heavily opinion-based: [https://worldbuilding.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6168/sandbox-for-proposed-questions]

Comment: Did it make a sub-orbital hop from the planet, or is it from some other planet? Is the ship still under some control, or is just crashing blindly? Meteorites strike all over Earth. I don't know if the distribution is uniform or biased to the equator or what, but I don't see any reason to think that area on your map couldn't have something crash there.

Comment: What was the spacecraft doing before it crash landed?

Comment: How many darts can I throw at your map? Nice map, but a space ship could literally crash *anywhere*. Please take a look at the [help] and [tour] to get a good idea of the kinds of questions allowable here.

Comment: Are you asking where it would crash (given no more information, anywhere), or assuming it will crash at Pike's Point and trying to figure out why?

Comment: The likelihood of the spaceship landing depends on the characteristics of the spaceships orbit before it impacted. Was it in an equatorial orbit? A polar orbit? Geostationary? At what altitude? And if you give altitude, we need mass and radius of the planet. If you describe the orbital characteristics, then we can map a probability distribution over a spherical planet of where it would land. If the spacecraft wasn't in orbit at all and crashed into the planet from deep space, then the map of bolides in @Willk's answer is correct.

Answer (score 5):

If the ship is coming in randomly from space, it is like any other space debris.  Incoming asteroids hitting the earth do so at random.  It looks like more hit around the equator but this is a Mercator projection, and so those central squares contain relatively more area than those near the poles.

https://www.jpl.nasa.gov/news/news.php?feature=4380

[image]

But if your crew still has any control over the ship, I can think of a great reason they might want to come down near Pike's Point: they want to evade detection and discovery by the intelligent inhabitants of the planet.  Pikes point is a mountainous, remote peninsula and so unlikely to have villages or cities. I envision it like Baja California, or the Kamchatka peninsula.  The descent of the ship across the ocean to finish here is unlikely to be witnessed.  In this location the crew will have time to await rescue by their countrymen, or repair their ship before they are discovered.

Comment: Meteorites are actually more likely to hit near the equator, because most objects orbiting the sun are roughly in the plane of the Earth's orbit. With the Earth's 23 degree axial tilt, that means that wherever in the tropics that the sun is directly overhead at noon (the plane of the ecliptic) has the highest chance of being hit. If the ecliptic has a chance of 1, then the chance of any other point is sin($\theta$), where $\theta$ is the latitude difference between that point and the ecliptic.

Comment: @kingledion and yet, the graphic from Nasa in Wullk's post shows otherwise. There are lots of debris in space orbiting the sun in planes different from Earth too, enough that the distribution is practically random. In fact the debris close to our orbital plane have mostly been cleared out through the aeons.

Comment: I agree that Pike Point is the best place to avoid detection: it is out of the way, and isolated by the desert. Middle of the desert might have been better, but crash-landing in water is safer.